# Disable all clickable elements in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

(Windows)

Is this possible?

To be more precise; imagine a screenshot of the entire webpage; you can scroll through it, but since it's just a screenshot, you can't interact with it. It's just visuals.

Is this possible to do to a webpage, ideally as a toggle? So, you turn it on, the entire page becomes un-interactable, you scroll a bit, and then toggle it off and can click on links and such.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a go to the Firefox add-on
[Freeze, Tab Suspender](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/freeze-tab-suspender/):

> Right-click to suspend pages and save ram and cpu.